# Best algorithm for matching HTTP routes

Tags: algorithm, http, routes

I am building my own http router, I would like to know what algorithm would be the best to register path in some data format and then to match it with http route request in the fastest way. I did a [Radix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), it's pretty fast, less than 1ms to match with a route but I don't have a big amount of routes registered and I am sure (as ignorant) that there is a faster way.

For example, let's take some uri routes :

- /hello
- /search
- /support
- /user/profile/(string)
- /user/info
- /post/(int)/view/(string)

My Radix Tree is doing this :

```
    /                
    ├s               
    |├earch         
    |└upport
    |      
    ├user\           
    |    └info
    |    └profile/
    |             └:string
    ├post\       
    |     └:int\/ 
    |          └/view/
    |                └/:string
    └hello
```

What do you thing about this tree, is there anything I can do better ?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Please provide us with a more complete description of your problem and include some code: either working code or pseudocode that outlines the algorithm that you used. Without both of those, it's difficult to provide a useful answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Radix Tree is actually a good way to implement that. Depending on how you implemented the nodes, you might be able to speed it up at the cost of some space.

If you define a node as:

```
Class Node
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Node> Children;
}
```

Then you have to do a sequential search on the children to find a matching segment. That's fine if the number of children for any node is relatively small. If you have a large number of children per node, then you might want to replace that `List<Node>` with a `Dictionary<string, Node>`. That will speed lookups.

Other than that, I can't think of a more appropriate data structure for the situation you describe.

Comment: With what type of data should I use as string reference in the dictonnary ? To avoid any conflicts.

Comment: @Zevran: Because each node has a dictionary of children, the string is the segment. For instance, in your example you have a top-level node called "user" and it has children "info" and "profile". So in your top-level dictionary, you would have an entry for "user", and in the "user" node the children dictionary would have entries with keys "info" and "profile". There is no chance of conflicts because the dictionaries are all separate.